# How can I drag the BorderLayout?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, draggable, border-layout

The border layout added by the code seems to be fixed. How can I drag the border?

For example, the effect in the picture:

[image]

Comment: Use a [`JSplitPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html) for a draggable divider between two containers. I use one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) to divide the space assigned to the table and the pic with an orange / yellow gradient.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.